# setTimeout is not working in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview

I m using Javascript function to expand/collapse the gridview rows. Following is the script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function divexpandcollapse(divname) {
        var div = document.getElementById(divname);
        var img = document.getElementById('img' + divname);
        if (div.style.display == "none") {
            div.style.display = "inline";
            img.src = "Img1/minus.gif";
        } else {
            div.style.display = "none";
            img.src = "Img1/plus.gif";
        }
    }
</script>
```

In my gridview I m calling the javascript like this, its working fine but its expanding immediately. I want to expand the panel slowly. Is that any incorrect coding  with the setTimeout function. Can anyone please help me...

```
    <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="20px">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <a href="JavaScript:setTimeout(divexpandcollapse('div<%# Eval("ClaimMasterId") %>'),1000);">
                <img id='imgdiv<%# Eval("ClaimMasterId") %>' width="9px" border="0" src="Img1/plus.gif"
                    alt="" /></a>                        
        </ItemTemplate>
        <ItemStyle Width="20px" VerticalAlign="Middle"></ItemStyle>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: can you use jquery?

Comment: i can use it but just want to know how to get that in jscript

Comment: Have you tried with: JavaScript:setTimeout(function() { divexpandcollapse('div<%# Eval("ClaimMasterId") %>'); },1000)

Comment: The easiest way of expanding something slowly would be to use CSS transitions.  That's beyond my expertise though, and is beyond the scope of the question as well.

Comment: thanks dario & thanks amy for clearing me...how can I achieve that using CSS transition

Comment: As per @dario, I have modified the question

Comment: If you want to ask about CSS transitions, please ask a new question.  Modifying this question to ask something different is not appropriate, especially after people have put in some effort to answer the original question.

Comment: ok sure, i can accept ur answer that was valid for the question asked but I couldn't see your answer, it shown as deleted. What happened and How can I accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because it's calling the function, taking the return value, and passing *that* to `setTimeout`, when what you're trying to do is call the method with `setTimeout` and pass in the arguments then.  So use [this overload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) instead:

```
window.setTimeout(func, [delay, param1, param2, ...]);
```

In your case, this would be:

```
setTimeout(divexpandcollapse ,1000, 'div<%# Eval("ClaimMasterId") %>')
```

See the difference?  `setTimeout` will call your method and pass in the parameters when it does so.

If you don't want to use that overload of `setTimeout`, you can enclose your method call inside another function:

```
setTimeout(function() { divexpandcollapse('div<%# Eval("ClaimMasterId") %>') }, 1000);
```

However, I find the first one far easier to read (and shorter to type).

Comment: yes, understood...it wait for 1 sec and then called

Comment: @Aruna If this answered your question to your satisfaction, I'd appreciate it if you accepted it as the answer.  That sweet, sweet rep.

Comment: but i would like to get the answer for transition effect which is the real need

Comment: That's not the question that was originally asked.